# Use a downloaded .cls class to write an article with Overleaf

Tags: document-classes, overleaf

I want to write an article using a specific .cls class that the editor of the journal requires. I am using Overleaf to write my article, so I would like to know how can I create the document using the downloaded class.
Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Normally, just putting the `.cls` file in the same project/directory as the mail file should just work.

Comment: Apparently it works! Thanks! Sometimes things are easier than expected